# Accessing Mongodb data using an alternative to _id

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I think this is a simple one, but I'm missing it. Currently I'm pulling in data from mongodb using node.js. I'm using Mongoose.

Here's my REST setup:

```
app.get( '/api/screens/:id', function( request, response ) {
return ScreenModel.findById( request.params.id, function( err, screen ) {
    if( !err ) {
        return response.send( screen );
    } else {
        return console.log( err );
    }
});
});
```

The model:

```
var Screen = new mongoose.Schema({
    resuls: String,
    choices: String,
    difficulty: String,
    _id: Number,
    screen: Number
});
```

Now this is currently working, but I don't want to use the _id to select the document. So my question is: how can I select a document using an alternative to the _id? Like if I wanted to access a document by its 'screen' number, or its 'difficulty' rating? How would this work?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ScreenModel.find( { screen: number_to_find }, function( err, result ) {
...
});
```